# How to Create a Boundary / Manipulate / Change Values of a Numpy Array

Tags: python, numpy

Imagine the Image below to be a (64,64) 2D Numpy array. How do I make this Numpy array which has zeros (0) as a boundary to pick out a smaller region (Highlighted in Green). It does not matter which region it picks (as long as it is on the upper-middle-right region of the array). The final result should look like the image on the right where every other value is 0 apart from the ones highlighted in Green?
[image]

Comment: what did you try? Where is your code? did you try to use normal `arr[y1:y2, x1:x2] = 0` with different values to run it 4 times - once for top row, once for bottom row, once for left column, and once for right column?

Comment: or maybe first create array64x64 only with zeros, and copy expected region `a[3:5,4:6] = b[3:5,4:6]`.

Comment: I did try to split it like the method, but it removes those zeros that I need. I will try your solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understand problem but you can create array 64,64 with zeros and copy green region from previous array.

To make it more visible I use array `(10,10)`

```
import numpy as np

#SIZE = 64
SIZE = 10

old_arr = np.random.randint(10, size=(SIZE, SIZE))

new_arr = np.zeros((SIZE, SIZE))

new_arr[3:5,4:6] = old_arr[3:5,4:6]

print(old_arr)
print(new_arr)
```

Comment: Should the split be 30:50,40:60 in my case? as it is a (64,64) array but visually I have drawn only 8 boxes

Comment: if you have 8 boxes then every box has size `8x8` and you need `3*8 : 5*8, 4*8 : 6*8` instead of `3*10 : 5*10, 4*10 : 6*10`